# Adding UIImage list to an Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I'm trying to code up a simple animation in Swift using a set of 13 .png files via an array of type UIImage. The code is breaking on the following line:

```
imageList += UIImage(named: imageName)
```

With the error message "Argument type UIImage does not conform to expected type 'sequence'"

I'm new to Swift. After declaring the array as type UIImage does anybody know why I'm seeing this error? I'm coding in XCode 8.0 Thanks a lot. Full code below:

```
var imageList = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in 1...13 {
        let imageName = "\(i)"
        imageList += UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not  creating an array with `UIImage`

try this way

```
var imageList = [UIImage]()
```

and should use append

```
imageList.append(UIImage(named: imageName)!)
```